# I forgot my bitcoin core passphrase. Is there anyway I can recover?

Tags: wallet-recovery, passphrase

I've tried brute forcing it. Doesn't work.

0.02 BTC in the wallet.

Comment: No. Fortunately, there is no way to recover a password. Otherwise, it was not secure and someone else could have stolen your bitcoins. The best you can do is waiting a few days. Maybe you remember the password or you remember where you wrote it down. And for the case that you remember in 10 years -> don't delete your wallet.

Comment: If you could brute force it, someone else can. Unless you've had a revelation and remembered your passphrase, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The whole point of strong encryption is that it is impossible to recover the data without the passphrase.

You can:

- Keep trying to brute force (maybe with faster computers, or a better initial guess at the passphrase)
- See if you have a backup of the wallet.dat file that isn't encrypted
- Try really hard to remember
- Give up, and resolve to be more careful with strong encryption next time.