# How to unlock private key of bitcoin

Tags: recover-private-key

[image]

I need help on how to get the private key....i  have that much on my account and i want to cash out very soon

Comment: Where did you make your original bitcoin wallet? if you do not hold the private keys you do not own the bitcoins... just saying

Answer (score 5):

People with 86 million dollars generally don't need to ask this.

People who have been tricked by con-artists are the sort of people that usually ask this.

That looks like a "blockchain" wallet.

---

> **How to unlock private key of bitcoin**

If you have forgotten a password needed to "unlock" your wallet, you have lost all your bitcoins and will either never get them back or will spend many months and tens of thousands of dollars in the attempt.

If you are having problems with your account at blockchain.com you need to contact blockchain.com. They are a Luxembourg company. See https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us - If you have been tricked, they won't be able to help you.

---

> **I  need help on how to get the private key**

You can follow the guidance on blockchain.com's support web-pages

[Exporting the private key](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003653543-Exporting-the-private-key-for-your-Ethereum-address). The example given is for Ethereum but you should choose "Bitcoin" instead.

If your wallet doesn't have a private key for the bitcoin-address holding those 86 million dollars worth of Bitcoin, it means you have a watch-only address imported into your wallet.

If someone tells you that you need to pay them to release the private-key, it means they are a con-artist tricking you into giving them more money.

---

#### Backups

If you were not tricked but didn't make a backup of your wallet and a written backup of your password, private key or a written backup of your recovery phrase, and have lost or forgotten them -- you have been very negligent.

Recovery may be very very difficult, time-consuming, expensive, or quite likely, impossible.

#### Scams by con-artists

If an online friend/miner/consultant set this up for you, it means you are the victim of a scam.

If so, it is quite possible that the money you are looking at is money in the wallet of some innocent third-party whose bitcoin-address has been imported by a scammer into your wallet as a "watch-only" address. In which case it was never your money and any money you sent to the scammer was pocketed by them completely separately.

---

#### Useful Links

Some other questions whose answers *might* be helpful in understanding your situation.

- Watch-only addresses

  - [Watch only wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/67253/13866)
  - [Reg: Watch only Address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75883/13866)
  - [I have watched addresses in my wallet..how do i use them?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74024/13866)
  - [Unlocking a Private Key from watch status](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/73541/13866)
- Private keys

  - [i lost access to my bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/76742/13866)
  - [Why were private keys made unrecoverable?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/72859/13866)
  - [Where do I obtain private keys?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/72609/13866)
  - [How to retrieve unclaimed BTC for wallets whose private key is lost](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/71569/13866)
- "Unlock private key"

  - [Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3313/13866)
  - [I forgot my bitcoin core passphrase. Is there anyway I can recover?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66201/13866)