# Non spendable bitcoin

Tags: blockchain.info

I downloaded the app because the person who was helping me said they can’t transfer my profits to my luno account and he asked for all my login details now there’s non spendable bitcoin he’s saying I should pay money for the for me to be able to withdraw please kindly assist me urgently

Comment: This is a scam. Don't respond.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlock private key of bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/77742/how-to-unlock-private-key-of-bitcoin) or of [How can I get a private key for this address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74362/13866)